# How do I extend jquery.mobile.scrollview?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to add a bit of code to `jquery.mobile.scrollvew` that exposes the time of the last `dragMove` event. It's would be really handy if I could add my own event to the `_handleDragMove` event but I don't really see how to do this.

I'm considering making a new widget that extends from `scrollview`, but that seems like a lot of work for 2 lines of code.

```
lastStopTime: 0,  // MED add a property
_handleDragMove: function(e, ex, ey)
{

    // MED added this timing hack to check to see if we are scrolling
    $.mobile.scrollview.prototype.lastStopTime = getCurrentTime();
    // MED

    this._lastMove = getCurrentTime();

    var v = this._$view;
}
```

a friend on g+ gave me the following snippet and it works great.  I can use the regular scrollview widget and add in some of my own code:

```
$.mobile.scrollview.prototype._handleDragMove = (function() {
    var origDragMove = $.mobile.scrollview.prototype._handleDragMove;
    return function __handleDragMove() {
        // Your code
        origDragMove.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}());
```

I think that's about what I'm looking for even if it's syntactically heavy.

Answer (score 0):

See :

```
$.extend()
```

jQuery function :D

Comment: I thought extend was for creating my own widget.  I'm trying to avoid that.  I have something that works and I'll update my original post with that code.